# How to set environment variable in container from Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to set an environment variable (I'll just name it `ENV_VAR_VALUE`) to a container during deployment through Kubernetes.

I have the following in the pod yaml configuration:

```
...
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appname-service
        image: path/to/registry/image-name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
        env:
        - name: "ENV_VAR_VALUE"
          value: "some.important.value"
...
...
```

The container needs to use the `ENV_VAR_VALUE`'s value.
But in the container's application logs, it's value always comes out empty.
So, I tried checking it's value from inside the container:

```
$ kubectl exec -it appname-service bash
root@appname-service:/# echo $ENV_VAR_VALUE
some.important.value
root@appname-service:/#
```

So, the value was successfully set.

I imagine it's because the environment variables defined from Kubernetes are set **after** the container is already initialized.

So, I tried overriding the container's CMD from the pod yaml configuration:

```
...
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: appname-service
        image: path/to/registry/image-name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
        env:
        - name: "ENV_VAR_VALUE"
          value: "some.important.value"
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["-c", "application-command"]
...
...
```

Even still, the value of `ENV_VAR_VALUE` is still empty during the execution of the command.
Thankfully, the application has a restart function
-- because when I restart the app, `ENV_VAR_VALUE` get used successfully.
-- I can at least do some other tests in the mean time.

#### So, the question is...

> How should I configure this in Kubernetes so it isn't a tad too late in setting the environment variables?

As requested, here is the Dockerfile.
I apologize for the abstraction...

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y some-dependencies

COPY application-script.sh application-script.sh

RUN ./application-script.sh

# ENV_VAR_VALUE is set in this file which is populated when application-command is executed
COPY app-config.conf /etc/app/app-config.conf

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "application-command"]
```

Comment: You might need to share the Dockerfile for the container

Comment: I added the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also running two commands in Kubernetes POD spec:

1. (read in env vars): "source /env/required_envs.env" (would come via [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) mount in volume)
2. (main command): "application-command"

Like this:

---

```
containers:
  - name: appname-service
    image: path/to/registry/image-name
    ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - source /env/db_cred.env;
        application-command;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the

```
RUN ./application-script.sh
```

below

```
COPY app-config.conf /etc/app/app-config.conf
```

Looks like the app is running before the env conf is available for it.

Comment: Because the /etc/app directory is only available after the `application-script.sh` execution is completed. Yes, that's exactly my problem. `application-command` executes before `ENV_VAR_VALUE` is populated from Kubernetes.

Comment: Then it's matter of doing a `RUN mkdir /etc/app` or splitting the script appropriately.

Comment: But that won't change anything. The problem lies in the fact that `ENV_VAR_VALUE` is populated by the command in CMD. Kubernetes needs to run the container to be able to set the environment variable. When the container is initialized first, then the environment variable setting is too late. I guess this is a dead-end?

Comment: The environment variable is not just for  the CMD. You can try doing `RUN echo $ENV_VAR_VALUE` to see. You can even try using the `ENV` command in dockerfile.